# C++/CLI Compilation Error (Fields)

Tags: .net, c++-cli

I have a C++/CLI class that looks like this:

```
#include "Stdafx.h"
#include "CLRIncludes.h"
#using <mscorlib.dll>

#pragma managed
namespace Ophidian {
    public ref class EngineConfigParams {
    private: 
    public:
        Int32 AdapterNumber;
        Int32 DisplayNumber;
        Boolean Fullscreen;
        UInt32 ResolutionX;
        UInt32 ResolutionY;
    };
}
```

Defined in "EngineConfigParams.h".

However, compilation fails with the following errors, repeated for each field:

> error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier
>   'AdapterNumber'
>   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

I get the feeling this is a configuration error more than a syntax one... But I can't be sure. Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do note that the usual C++ types such as `int` and `unsigned` and `bool` also work just fine in managed code, and in fact compile to the same exact thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was to import the System namespace:

```
using namespace System;
```

Comment: Note that the use of `using namespace` at global scope in headers is disrecommended (though IIRC, you should be able to use it at class scope).